# Смайлики: быть или не быть?

Tags: общие-вопросы, пунктуация

Тут как-то уже поднималась эта тема. Но сейчас, почитав обсуждение интернет-мемов, я подумал: а чем, собственно, смайлики существенно отличаются от знаков препинания, в частности вопросительного и восклицательного знака? Они ведь тоже определяют цель высказывания, просто, у них спектр эмоций шире.
Понятно, что в литературной речи в них нет необходимости, потому что автор всегда поясняет, как была сказана та или иная фраза. А в более сухой речи и том же интернет-общении, мне кажется, они просто незаменимы.
Вы только подумайте: скольких ссор, конфликтов и даже разрывов дружбы удалось избежать, благодаря смайликам. Ведь не всегда понятно по оттенку речи, как была сказана фраза: с иронией, в шутку или с желанием оскорбить.
Как вы считаете, должны ли смайлики стать узаконенным знаком препинания?

Comment: Это голосование? или сбор подписей в защиту (за отмену)?.. Не совсем понятно, как отвечать на такой вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смайлики уже так прочно вошли в обиход, что уже не представляю, как человечество сможет от них отказаться.

Всё меняется в мире очень быстро. Вполне допускаю мысль, что когда-нибудь станут на клавиатурах делать специальные клавиши. 
Потом смайликам придадут статус знаков препинания. В школах будут мучить детей новыми правилами.

Другой вариант: придумают что-то новенькое. Тогда по употреблению вышедших из моды смайликов можно будет легко узнать в интернете старшее поколение.

Answer (score 3):

> Ведь не всегда понятно по оттенку речи, как была сказана фраза: с иронией, в шутку или

По этому поводу где-то услышала:
- Молодой человек занервничал, когда на  вопрос "как дела?" его девушка ответила: "Пока не родила", а смайлика в конце не было.

Answer (score 3):

Формализация - вещь условная, произойдёт она или нет - дело второе. В любом случае сторонники и противники будут всегда, как у буквы "ё" например.В реальности смайлики давно занимают положение знаков препинания: у них свой функционал для выражения эмоций и интонации. 
То, что смайлики будут неуместны в резюме не говорит о том, чт их не нужно формально закреплять, просторечная лексика тоже не уместна в резюме, так как это официально-деловой стиль, тем не менее, она пласт нашего родного языка. Нет смысла отрицать то, что входит в нашу жизнь. Есть смысл только думать над вопросами: "Хорошо или плохо?" И "Формализовывать или нет?". Первый вопрос очень философский, на эту тему каждый может приводить свои аргументы, я уже сказал выше, что ничего плохого в смайликах не вижу, так как функционально они мало отличимы от знаков пунктуации. А вот форально закреплять, думаю, не стоит. Пока нет такой необходимости, спектр применения ещё действительно узок, хотя время вскоре может внести свои коррективы. В школе детей точно не будут учить новым правилам, потому что смайлики - это субъективные знаки: только сам говорящий-пишущий может решать, с какими эмоциями он произносит свою реплику, интонацией при диктанте или содержанием предложения в письменном виде это не передать.

P.S. Спасибо, интересную тему затронули.

Answer (score 2):

При всей моей симпатии к такому интересному инструменту речи, как смайлики, думаю, не стоит их когда-либо "узаконивать". Сфера применения довольно узкая: только неформальное общение. В формальном же общении лучше обходиться без них, иначе это может расцениваться как фамильярность. Например, соискателей, резюме или письма которых содержат смайлы, скорее всего всерьез не воспримут (как и тех, кто отправляет резюме с эл. адресов типа zajchonok@..., nimfomanka@...).

Comment: Давайте тогда "не узаконивать" слова "старина" или "дурак", их тоже в официальной речи нет!
Ненене, явление прочно вошло в жизнь. Игнорировать его для филолога - это всё равно что отрицать силу тяжести.

Answer (score 1):

Попытаюсь прямо ответить на конкретные вопросы.

1) От вопросительного и восклицательного знаков смайлики отличаются тем, что среди них нет таких знаков.

2) На основной вопрос, наверное, может быть только один прямой ответ. Для него есть даже специальный *мем*: "всем пофиг".

По неписаным правилам форумного этикета, в конце второго пункта должен был бы стоять именно самый наиклассический смайлик - :-). Но я как раз вчера перечитывал одну книгу, и... Не скажу, что я на 100% согласен с героиней, но всё же:

> -- Интересно, где ты этого набралась?
>
> -- Я не набралась. Я сама так думаю.
>
> -- В «Живом Журнале», - сказал я, - после такой фразы полагалось бы
> поставить смайлик.
>
> -- А смайлик - это визуальный дезодорант. Его обычно ставят, когда
> юзеру кажется, что от него плохо
> пахнет. И он хочет гарантированно
> пахнуть хорошо.